# Finding portions of a 'multi-day' datetime range falling within/outside daily datetime variable range(s)

Tags: oracle, datetime, plsql, sql-timestamp

How to solve this in Oracle SQL?

1.I have Columns **Event_Min_DateTime** (eg. 01/06/2017 7:30:00) & **Event_Max_datetime** (eg. 03/06/2017 18:30:00) of an **Event_ID** (eg. ev001). So a calculated column **Event_minutes** can be created as (**Event_Max_datetime** - **Event_Min_DateTime**)*24*60.

2. I also have columns **Daily_Window_Start** (variable TimeStamp Value) and **Daily_Window_End** (variable TimeStamp Value) of a **Daily_Date** (Sequentially every day). So a calculated column **Daily_Window_minutes** can be calculated as (**Daily_Window_End** - **Daily_Window_Start**)*24*60. Note, **Daily_Window_minutes** will always be <=1440.

Now, how to calculate the columns **Daily_portion_within** (portion of the **Event_minutes**  falling within **Daily_Window_minutes**) and **Daily_portion_outside** (portion of the **Event_minutes**  falling outside **Daily_Window_minutes** but within the same **Daily_Date** )?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from the question if Daily_Window_Start can be >  Event_Min_DateTime, so here I have considered to write for only such cases where it is not. Also since, datatypes of columns are not apparent from your question and conversion is not applied. You can write your queries on the similar lines for Daily_Window_Start  >  Event_Min_DateTime as specified below. There are many  assumptions here however.

```
   SELECT
           CASE
                  WHEN e. event_max_datetime <= d.daily_window_end THEN (e.event_max_datetime - e.event_min_datetime)*24*60
                  ELSE (d.daily_window_end                                                    - e.event_min_datetime)*24*60
           END daily_portion_within ,
           CASE
                  WHEN e. event_max_datetime <= d.daily_window_end THEN NULL
                  ELSE ( e.event_max_datetime - d.daily_window_end)*24*60
           END daily_portion_outside
    FROM   (
                  SELECT Trunc(event_max_datetime) dt ,
                         event_min_datetime ,
                         event_max_datetime
                  FROM   EVENTS ) EVENTS e,
           daily_window d
    WHERE  e.dt = trunc(d.dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

This example should help:

```
select trunc(d1) as day, inside, (d2 - d1) * 24 * 60 - inside as outside 
  from (select e.*, d.*,
               case when d2 < e1 or e2 < d1 then 0
                    else least(e2, d2) - greatest(e1, d1)
               end * 24 * 60 as inside
          from e cross join d)
```

Data:

```
create table e (id number(3), e1 date, e2 date);
insert into e values(1, timestamp '2017-06-01 07:30:00', timestamp '2017-06-03 18:30:00');

create table d (d1 date, d2 date);
insert into d values(timestamp '2017-06-01 06:00:00', timestamp '2017-06-01 15:30:00');
insert into d values(timestamp '2017-06-02 09:30:00', timestamp '2017-06-02 22:30:00');
insert into d values(timestamp '2017-06-03 12:05:00', timestamp '2017-06-03 19:45:00');
insert into d values(timestamp '2017-06-04 15:00:00', timestamp '2017-06-04 16:30:00');
```

Result:

```
DAY             INSIDE    OUTSIDE
----------- ---------- ----------
2017-06-01         480         90
2017-06-02         780          0
2017-06-03         385         75
2017-06-04           0         90
```